# Is there a way to scale the height and width by parent div?

Tags: css

I am wondering if there is a way in css to scale the div's width and height by parents div.

```css
.div1{
 width: 150px;
 height: 150px;
 background-color: blue;
}
.div2 {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class = "div1">
  <div class = "div2">
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way for the div2 to be the same width and height as div1 by changing div1 css only?

I know I can use 100%, or percentages in div2,  but the problem is that I am not able to modify the inner div and the inner divs have concerete width and height. And also, div has padding and margins combined with like 50 other divs, so I am wondering if theres a easier way to do this?

Thanks for all the help!

thank you for all the help

Comment: Doesn't seem like a problem to me. That's how code works. Do you just want to center the inner divs? If they have a concrete width and height, how would they change size? CSS does support `transform:scale();`, but that might be a real hassle in this case. Please make your question more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.div2{
  width:inherit;
  height:inherit;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose If you've:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Child
  </div>
</div>
```

then you can just add this inside parent's and child's css and It should work just fine:

```
.parent {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.child {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```